# WiMAX in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, kernel

About two weeks ago I asked a question about how to connect to WiMAX. And today I have done some research, and I want to share it with everyone. I don't know if this is going to be useful for someone, but at least I tried.
I downloaded the wimax master tools from GitHub and installed it. I know (from Windows) that WiMAX and wifi cannot work together in the same card (I’m using the 6150 Intel) so I did:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi 
sudo modprobe wimax
dmesg | grep WiMAX
```

and got a message saying:

```
i2400m_usb WiMAX interface wmx (mac address)  ready.
```

When you search Google for Ubuntu WiMAX driver, a file from kernel archives called "i2400m (...)" appears. When you open it,  you realize it is not a driver download, it is a readme file. In a line, it says that if you check the kernel logs, if it says "(...) WiMAX interface wmx0 (mac) ready", then the driver is ready. So my driver is ready.

I'm not a Linux expert (I’m only 13 years old), so my question is: How do I connect through wmx0 interface if my driver is ready? Thanks.

Comment: I would bet you still have the same issue I have and that is `rfkill list all` shows wimax as soft blocked and I haven't figured out how to unblock it and I end up with `i2400m_usb 1-1.6:1.0: 'RF Control' (0x4602) command failed: -84 - invalid state (3)` when I try `sudo rfkill unblock all`

Comment: Yes i do have that issue. I will try to figure out a way to unlock it, but i think the best way to do it is disabling iwlwifi, because wifi and wimax cannot work at the same time.

Comment: I even tried after soft blocking wifi and `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`   I think there is something in the BIOS on mine that prevents Ubuntu from removing the block.  My laptop is a Satellite M645 and if I use a wifi/bluetooth card in it, the wifi doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I will try asking my informatics professor.